# itextsharp 5.5.10 converting gridview to pdf in c# with a heading for pdf ? (beginner)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, itext

Every code found on net is either showing absolute or not working !Using dropdownlist on Ajax update panel and on its index change showing gridview.

Gridview is working . is there any better practice for converting pdf ? or help to convert gridview to pdf using itextsharp 5.5.10

Answer (score 0):

- First Pass Gridview Dt to Itextsharp function.

  - like **void PrintPDF(Datatable dt)**
  - then use below code for Datatable Printing .
  - **I've show you just little part of my code, You should design Table as per your requirement.**

    for (int k = 0; k < dt.Rows.Count; k++)
              {
                PdfPTable tableinside = new PdfPTable(1);
                tableinside.WidthPercentage = 100;
                tableinside.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                tableinside.DefaultCell.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;

    ```
            PdfPCell cell28 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dt.Rows[k]["Name"].ToString(), topfont1));
            cell28.BorderWidthTop = 0.5f;
            cell28.BorderWidthLeft = 0.5f;
            cell28.Border = 0;
            cell28.PaddingTop = 5f;
            cell28.PaddingLeft = 10f;
            cell28.PaddingBottom = 8f;
            cell28.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;
            tableinside.AddCell(cell28);
    ```

    }